# Cannot change XmlDocument value?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a simple function which will simply change and read the value.

```
void ParseXml(string XmlFile)
{
    string totalval = "";
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.Load(new StringReader(XmlFile));

    string xmlPathPattern = "//name";

    XmlNodeList mynodelist = xmldoc.SelectNodes(xmlPathPattern);
    foreach (XmlNode node in mynodelist)
    {
        XmlNode name = node.FirstChild;
        name.Value = "asd";//here I am trying to change value
        totalval = totalval + "Name=" + name.OuterXml + "\n";
    }

    xmldoc.Save(XmlFile);
    print(totalval);
}
```

This is my **.xml** file.

```
<name>John</name>
```

I can successfully read the value but it is not changing the value from **.xml** file.After running the program it must be  like this
    `<name>asd</name>` . 
 Where is my mistake ?

Comment: Include also xml file

Comment: Are you looking at the correct file after the program ran ?

Comment: @Frederik Gheysels Finally it is working.I just forget about changing path last time. Thank you.You were right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, the `XMLFile` is not a file path, it is xml string. So, you should define a valid path to save it.

```
xmldoc.Save("samplefile.xml");
```

or if you want to set the `XmlFile` variable with modified xml;

```
XmlFile = xmldoc.OuterXml;
```

Complete codes look like;

```
void ParseXml(string XmlFile)
{
    string totalval = "";
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.Load(new StringReader(XmlFile));

    string xmlPathPattern = "//name";

    XmlNodeList mynodelist = xmldoc.SelectNodes(xmlPathPattern);
    foreach (XmlNode node in mynodelist)
    {
        XmlNode name = node.FirstChild;
        name.Value = "asd";//here I am trying to change value
        totalval = totalval + "Name=" + name.OuterXml + "\n";
    }
    //XmlFile = xmldoc.OuterXml;
    xmldoc.Save("samplefile.xml");
    print(totalval);
}
```

Comment: It gives me the error `ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted (System.String path)`

Comment: what is the "XmlFile" ?

Comment: `<name>John</name>` it is string

Comment: Thank you I already found the solution. After ran I was not looking correct file

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong - you need to fire disposable to save stream. Easiest way - wrap with `using`

```
void ParseXml(string XmlFile)
{
    string totalval = "";
    using(XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument()) 
    {
        xmldoc.Load(new StringReader(XmlFile));

        string xmlPathPattern = "//name";
        XmlNodeList mynodelist = xmldoc.SelectNodes(xmlPathPattern);
        foreach (XmlNode node in mynodelist)
        {
            XmlNode name = node.FirstChild;
            name.Value = "asd";//here I am trying to change value
            totalval = totalval + "Name=" + name.OuterXml + "\n";
        }

        xmldoc.Save(XmlFile);
        print(totalval);
    }
}
```